# Ordenar salida de consulta en mongoose (find) por dos campos

Tags: json, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

No logro ordenar el resultado de una consulta en mongoose no se si sea necesario una función de agregación para lograr ese orden.

Tengo una columna que se llama _id y otra columna que se llama comment_id (que contiene el _id principal para hacer referencia). Esta e sla consulta que tengo:

```
exports.getCommentsByCollaboratorId = function (req, res) {
    Comments.find({'user_id': req.query._id})
        .populate({
            path: 'user_id',
            select: 'full_name'
        .populate({
            path: 'post_id',
            select: 'title blog_code subcategory'
        })
        .sort({_id: 1, comment_id: 1})
        .exec(function (err, comments) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({status:500, message: 'internal error', type:'internal'});
                return;
            }

            res.json(comments);
            console.log('200       /getCommentsByCollaboratorId');
        })

}
```

En esa consulta se hace un join para usuario y para los post, pero cuando se agrega un comentario queda al final cuando debería quedar en orden desde el comentario principal y todas sus respuestas, algo así:

El actual:

[image: Actual]

El deseado:

[image: Deseado]

Su ayuda es apreciada, un saludo.